# Chrome Extension: CRX file not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to install my Extension's CRX version but it is not loading some of image files on   extension button placed on address bar.I have even put try/catch but it is not giving any error either. The Developer/Unpack version is working just fine.

What's wrong am I doing? What I guess my all image files are not compressed in CRX file. Unfortunately I can't extract CRX content either as renamig to .ZIP is not letting me to unzip on MacoSX

I am installing CRX by dragging on to extensions page.
How do I test the issue?

Code is given below:

**Manifest.jsonn**

```
{
  "name": "Domain Colors",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Change Button Color for domains.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Colry",
    "default_icon": "blue.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background41.js"]
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```
alert("Testing Version..Wait for a while");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (request == null)
{
        alert("Unable to create request");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime(); //to avoid cache ajax calls
        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
        timestamp = timestamp * randomnumber;
        var _domain = document.domain;
        _domain = _domain.replace("www.","");
        var url = "http://xxxxnet/xxx/xxx.asp?xx="+_domain+"&ts="+timestamp;
        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            //request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
            //request.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
            if(request.readyState == 4)
            {
                LDResponse(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
    catch(e){
        alert('An error has occurred in AJAX Call: '+e.message)
    }
}

function LDResponse(response)
{
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(response);
    var msg = document.domain+","+json["buttonColour"]+","+json["buttonTip"];
    chrome.extension.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

**background file**

```
var currentUrl = "";
var currentColor = "";
var currentTip = "";

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'loading')
    {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path:'chrome-extension://lkhgldilknhpmdodeblhnbniahbjcdcm/gray.png',
            tabId:tabId
        });
        chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender)
        {
            try
            {
                var stuff = message.split(",");
                currentUrl = stuff[0];
                currentUrl = currentUrl.replace("www.","");
                currentColor = stuff[1];
                currentTip = stuff[2];
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert('An error in onMessage method: '+e.message)
            }
        });
    }
    else if (changeInfo.status === 'complete')
    {
        try
        {
           chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path:'chrome-extension://lkhgldilknhpmdodeblhnbniahbjcdcm/'+currentColor+".png",
            tabId:tabId
            });

            chrome.browserAction.setTitle({
              tabId:tabId,
              title:currentTip
            });
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert('An error in Complete method: '+e.message)
        }

    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Share your code? did you use chrome.extension.getURL()?

Comment: @Sudarshan Code added in Original Post. It's successfully making HTTP calls. It's just not loading green/red.png images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `path:'chrome-extension://lkhgldilknhpmdodeblhnbniahbjcdcm/'+currentColor+".png` with `path: chrome.extension.getURL("currentColor.png")` to get it to work.

Your runtime extension id is not `lkhgldilknhpmdodeblhnbniahbjcdcm`, so to use dynamic generated content you should use [`chrome.extension.getURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL)

Comment: LOve it! Thans Bro. It did work at my end.I am sending to client to know his feedback.I accepted it because I believe this was the issue.

Comment: @Volatil3: replace all the occurrence's for `gray.png` also